# Issue in uploading markdown results in Algolia Dashboard using gatsby-plugin-algolia

Tags: gatsby, algolia

I was trying to integrate Alogolia Search with a Gatsby site using **gatsby-plugin-algolia**. Below is the code from *gatsby-config* to query markdown files content and push it to algolia for indexing .

```js
require("dotenv").config({
  path: ".env",
})
const blogQuery = `query {
  allMarkdownRemark {
    nodes {
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
      excerpt
    }
  }
}
`
const queries = [
  {
    query: blogQuery,
    transformer: ({ data }) => data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes,
  },
]

module.exports = {

  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-algolia",
      options: {
        appId: process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
        apiKey: process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY,
        indexName: process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME, // for all queries
        queries,
        cunkSize: 1000,
      },     
    ],
}
```

I have verified API keys in .env file also checked in graphQL playground that **blogQuery** returns results.
Here is the result of localhost:8000/__graphQL
[image]

When I run **gatsby build** I get below error :
[image]

I also tried to debug error in generated log, but could not figure out more :
[image]

Kindly let me know what I am missing as Algoia API keys are correct and graphQL query fetches records.
PS: Using Node *10.16.0* 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectID was missing in the query :

```js
const blogQuery = `query {
  allMarkdownRemark {
    nodes {
      objectID: id
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
      excerpt
    }
  }
}`
```

However docs say if objectID is missing , Algolia will automatically insert but it was not working.